# Node JS and Socket.IO. Client getting disconnected. During request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

I've ran into a fairly difficult to debug error with my node web server.

**Background**
I'm creating a node server with socket.io to provide a restful service, connected to mongodb which use web sockets(socket.io) for server-client messages.

**Issue**
In my node app, I've used an npm package called node-scheduler, in which I do some processing at set times(these are very dynamic times but work fairly well to date).

So I'll set off a job, using node-scheduler and when it ends you can provide a function.

In this function I emit a web socket message, exactly how I emit messages in the rest of the application but my client side never receives the message.

Checking the logs the client disconnections then re connections after the function has completed.

I've debugged a little further, and I send two messages to the client in this function.  Only one of them is processed by the client.  May be a client issue not a server issue.

Any ideas for solutions or suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well generally socket.io is only meant to be used as a "channel". You should have the Client exist as a separate entity in memory or something, and update the socket if and when it reconnects. Otherwise you're just sending to the past (disconnected) sockets.

Using [passport](http://passportjs.org/) you can identify a client as a user.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // req.user;
});
```

Using [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) you can get the same user in your socket

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    // socket.request.user;

    socket.request.user.socket = socket;
    // this will be updated with the latest socket in case of a future reconnection
    // So now you can be sure that user object will always have the latest socket

    nodeScheduler(function(){
        carryOutJobs(function callback(){
            socket.request.user.socket.emit('done');
            // will always emit to the "latest" socket.
        });
    });
});
```